# background image toggle and hidden select check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/dhaileytaha/ghuj4jL8/1/

The above is a fiddle in which i want to toggle or show/hide the background image(i.e. tick mark) `onclick` and also select the following offer in database `(mysql)`. I am able to show the tick mark but not hide it. Please help.

```
$(function() {
  $('.listing-content').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg1Do.png)');
 });
})
```

Comment: When a `listing-content` element is clicked, you need the other `listing-content` elements to have the background image removed also? So no more than one is ticked at a time?

Comment: yes can please do it

Answer (score 3):

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rajan_Singh/ghuj4jL8/2/)

You can use `toggleClass` of jQuery for doing that :

Comment: can u guide me how to select the row id of mysql also through that click??

Comment: Can you tell me what you actually want on that click as I can see there is no id on any row ?

Comment: i want a hidden check box which also selects the row in mysql ? its not in the fiddle thats y asked u to just guide me

Comment: I think you want the ID of row on which tick is there, so you can code like `if($(this).hasClass("myClass")){ $(this).attr("id") }` , this will get you id for selected row if there exists any id on that row.

Comment: i am executing the details of the offer template through mysql db so i want to select the row id of the particular offer comin from db. Is that ur solution?

Comment: You can give Id to row in your HTML template, the above will fetch id if the row gets selected & on basis of that you can select row from your mysql db.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help but if i want to select only one template not more than one what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Here you can use addClass and remove Class method.
```

you can  write a class called "tickMark" in that you give background-image       property and you  add the class  and remove the class dynamically.

https://jsfiddle.net/ghuj4jL8/4/